# "Terminate" in eclipse's console view leaves node.exe running

Tags: eclipse, windows, node.js, express, console

I recently started developing for Node.js/Express with [Nodeclipse](http://www.nodeclipse.org/). I added a run configuration for `package.json` with goal `start`. This works as expected, the `start` command from `package.json` is executed (`node ./bin/www`). I can see this command in Eclipse's console view and I can see two `node.exe` processes appear in Windows Task-Manager. HTTP requests to `http://localhost:3000/` are logged in the console.

However, klicking the red "Terminate"-Button in Eclipse's console view leaves the `node.exe` processes running. Subsequent attempts to start the app fail because the port is already in use.

I do not have this problem when I start the app with `npm start` in Windows `cmd`. Stopping the execution with Ctrl+C will also exit the node.exe processes.

This is my IDE-Setup:

- Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2) under Windows 7 x64 with jre1.8.0_45
- Eclipse was setup this way: extracted eclipse-platform-4.4.2-win32-x86_64.zip (from [here](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.4.2-201502041700/)), installed Eclipse Marketplace Client, then installed Nodeclipse via Drag&Drop from nodeclipse.org
- Node.js version v0.12.2 (for Windows x64)
- express-generator (version 4.12.1) is installed globally

How can I make the Terminate button in the console view actually terminating the node.exe processes?

Comment: It's possible that you are hitting  terminate in the nodeclipse console. Look for your application's console and hit terminate button there.

Comment: I see only one console which is titled `package.json [NPM] NPM Process start`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Eclipse only kills the npm script that is used to start up node. The thing is that Eclipse forcibly kills that script, giving it no chance to send any signals to the node.exe process.

This [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=64230) explains why this works this way.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Step 1:
Run command-line as an Administrator. Then run the below mention command. type your port number in yourPortNumber
netstat -ano | findstr :yourPortNumber

Red coloured circled area shows the PID (process identifier)

Step 2 :
Then you execute this command after identify the PID.
taskkill /PID typeyourPIDhere /F

P.S. Run the first command again to check if process is still available or not. You'll get empty line if process is successfully ended.